# Define margins for some elements

Tags: margins

Is it possible for elements on a page to have different margins? In short, I would like the gray box to span the width of the page but everything else should have a 1cm margin on all sides. The approach I took is to set margin of 1cm on all sides and explicitly give the gray box 0 margin. This does not work, see code and more details below.

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{color, xcolor}
\usepackage{moresize, fontawesome}
\definecolor{darkcol}{RGB}{ 70, 70, 70 }
\definecolor{maincol}{RGB}{ 225, 0, 0 }

% Minipage width minus 2 times fboxsep
\newcommand{\mpwidth}{\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxsep}

% Section command
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1] {
    \vspace{14pt}
    \cvtext{
        \textbf{\LARGE{\textcolor{darkcol}{\uppercase{#1}}}}\\[-4pt]
        \textcolor{maincol}{ \rule{0.1\textwidth}{2pt} } \\
    }
}

\newcommand{\cvtext}[1] {
    \begin{tabular*}{1\mpwidth}{p{0.98\mpwidth}}
        \parbox{1\mpwidth}{#1}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0cm}
\geometry{top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\fcolorbox{white}{darkcol}{\begin{minipage}[c][5.5cm][c]{1\mpwidth}
    \begin {center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a.png}

        \HUGE{ \textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ \uppercase{Name} } } }\\
        \openup 1em % Add space between Name and Role - other options don't work
        \huge {{\textcolor{white}{Role}}}
        \openup -1em % Undo extra line spacing command
        
        \textcolor{white}{ \rule{1\textwidth}{1.25pt} }
        \normalsize \textcolor{white} {phone number | email}
    \end {center}
\end{minipage}}
\restoregeometry

\vfill\null
\cvsection{PROFILE}
\cvtext{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to add `\tab` to commands like cvsection but latex does not respond to that. Other solutions I have tried (like the current one `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` change the margin as desired but move the content onto the next page.

Comment: Please make your examples complete hence compilable. For example, fix the missing `\documentclass` and missing `document` environments.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ cvtext was missing in the example and has been added to the bottom.

Comment: You are not understanding the request.  Please make the example ***complete***, meaning, begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  It is requested that all questions provide such an example.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ah ok, I was trying to make it more readable.